# managing two buttons on two separate windows in one win32 application...?

Tags: c++, winapi

I don't know if I would be able to explain this. I am creating TCP implementation consisting of four clients and one server so that the server can update all clients about something important. On every window there is a button to send text (for clients , it would send to the server. And for server, clicking it will send to all clients)

Everything is working fine, the code compiled successfully and the server is sending the updates to all clients. The problem that i am facing is something according to me fairly complex. The problem is when i use the button on the client window to send something to server by editing on the editor window.....server doesn't receive that but receives the same updates that it has sent to all clients.

let me explain this with an example:

suppose there are windows in front of you-one of server and four for clients, each having a button (for the function that has been explained above)....now suppose that clients are connected with the server and receives an update from the server that.....say "a has become 4".... and at this time if one of the client decides to send something to the server....say "ok, i received the message!!" and clicks the send button on its window after typing this message and tailing it with its name ....say..."\r\n------sent from client number : 1-----".....
so now the message has become:

```
ok, i received the message!!
------sent from client number : 1-----
```

and now if the client tries to send this message to server....the server receives it and further tails it with the message..."\r\n From client number 1\r\n".....so now the message that should be printed on the windows screen is...:-

```
 ok, i received the message!!
------sent from client number : 1-----
From client number 1
```

but , the server receives is :-

```
a has become 4
  ------sent from client number : 1-----
  From client number 1
```

what could be the problem....???

Comment: We will need to see code.

Comment: *"what could be the problem....???"* - Your code. Where is it?

Comment: problem solved ....thank you for the comments.

Comment: Please indicate how you solved the problem.